# Indexed MySQL field not saving value when creating/editing record through ADO

Tags: mysql, database, vba, ms-access, ado

I am using ADO to add a record to a MySQL table. The code works fine, and the data is posted to the new record, all except the `userid`. I can't figure out why.

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : IPhpList_AddHistory
' Author    : Adam
' Date      : 12/8/2014
' Purpose   : Add a history record to the phpList account.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Private Sub IPhpList_AddHistory(cUser As clsUser, cHistory As clsHistory)

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "phplist_user_user_history limit 0,1"
    rst.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    With rst
        .AddNew
            !userid = cUser.PhpListID
            !ip = ""
            ![Date] = cHistory.AddDate
            !Summary = cHistory.Subject
            !Detail = cHistory.Body
            !systeminfo = "Automated syncronization process. " & VBE.ActiveVBProject.Description
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    ' Clear reference
    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Seems simple enough, but the resulting record in MySQL is missing the `userid` value.

[image]

There is an index on the column, but it does not seem like this should prevent me from setting the value. (And no, there are no triggers on this table.)

[image]

When I step through the code, I can see that the value for this field is set, and there are no errors when the record is updated, but somehow it just reverts to zero when the record is added.

I realize that I can add the record using `.Execute(strSQL)`, but I would like to understand why the ADO code is having difficulty setting a value for this column.

Of further interest, when I go back and try to update the userid column on an existing record, I have a similar result. I set the value, and it reverts back to zero (or whatever previous value was there).

### Update

Now this is getting really perplexing... I added another column with the same data type, length, etc... to the table, and suddenly the code works as expected. I can edit the value in the new column ***and/or*** the `userid` column. (And edit the values independently)

But when I remove the test column, it goes back to the previous behavior, of not allowing me to change the value in `userid`. (why would this be??)

Taking things a step further, I created the table on a local MySQL instance so I could profile the ADO queries as they hit the database. This revealed some very interesting behavior. The following two statements were generated by the same ADO code, but the second one had the test column added to the table.

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`phplist_user_user_history`(`id`,`userid`,`ip`,`date`,`summary`,`detail`,`systeminfo`) 
VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT,'',_binary'2014-12-18 11:51:13','My Subject','New Details','IBLP automated syncronization process. Version 1.0')

INSERT INTO `test`.`phplist_user_user_history`(`id`,`userid`,`ip`,`date`,`summary`,`detail`,`systeminfo`,`testcol`) 
VALUES (DEFAULT,456,'',_binary'2014-12-18 13:22:44','My Subject','New Details','IBLP automated syncronization process. Version 1.0',1)
```

Notice how the first insert statement inputs `DEFAULT` instead of the value I passed through ADO.

The second calling code was identical, except that it set a value in `testcol`. Why would this run differently when there are two `INT(11)` columns instead of one?

[image]

A further clue is that when I run the code against the table in my test database, I get the following error in VBA (even though I am explicitly setting the userid value):

[image]

After adding the test column, the error then pops up on the test column. After explicitly setting the value on the test column, the `.Update` is successful, and both fields are updated correctly.

Could this possibly be a bug in the ODBC driver? I am using the latest MySQL ODBC connector driver (5.3.4), and the following connection string:

```
"Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver;SERVER=myserver;UID=myuser;PWD={mysecretpwd};DATABASE=test;PORT=3306;DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1"
```

Comment: Has this function ever worked? I am wondering if it is directly related to MySQL and not-so-much Access. Do you use this code when you "..go back and try to update the userid column on an existing record" ?

Comment: Good question. Yes, it does work, in the sense that every other field is updated correctly. (In both the original insertion, and when I use the same code to go back and change the existing record.) The only field I am unable to change is the `userid`.

Comment: Have you tried to throw in something that MySQL wouldn't accept? For instance, if it's an `integer` field, throw in "Test" or something. This may help narrow down at what stage the error occurs, and if it doesn't occur, we can safely deduct that something is *defaulting* `userid` to some value.

Comment: `![Date] = "someweirddate"` throws a "Type Mismatch" error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant specifically in the userid field

Comment: Sure. `!userid = "test"` throws the same error.

Comment: Just to clarify, is `oConn` a direct connection to a MySQL database, or is it a connection to an Access database that has an ODBC linked table pointing to a MySQL table?

Comment: @GordThompson - It is a direct ADO connection established through VBA code with the connection string shown in the revised description above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue with the 64-bit version of the MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver (5.03.04.00). It appears to be an issue with ADO Recordset updates when the last column in the table is of type `TEXT`. I did not even have an index on `userid` and I got the same results.

One possible workaround would be to use an `ADODB.Command` with parameters to perform the insert using code similar to this:

```vbs
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open _
        "Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver;" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "UID=root;" & _
        "PWD=whatever;" & _
        "DATABASE=mydb;" & _
        "PORT=3306;" & _
        "DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
cmd.CommandText = _
        "INSERT INTO phplist_user_user_history " & _
        "(`userid`, `ip`, `date`, `Summary`, `Detail`, `systeminfo`) " & _
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adInteger, adParamInput, , 456)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 255, Now)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "cHistory.Subject")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 2147483647, "cHistory.Body")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 2147483647, "Automated syncronization process.")
cmd.Execute

Set cmd = Nothing
oConn.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
```

I tested it from an Access 2010 database and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Just curious - was text the *only* data type this occurred with? Great research btw. +1

Comment: Thanks for the excellent work on this answer! I have submitted a bug report for the ODBC connector at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75275

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but it appears that the ADO is expecting the table to generate the key, so while it 'keeps' your keep around until it sends it to the database, it is only using it as a place holder.  And since the table isn't generating the key it defaults to 0.

Does the data definition for the IPhpList_AddHistory in the ADO have an AutoIncrement property set to true?  If so it should be false.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/09/14/refresh-the-primary-key-identity-column-during-insert-operation.aspx

Comment: Good idea, but no, `ISAUTOINCREMENT` is already set to false on this column. We don't have any special complex indexes set up (as shown above), and this is not even the primary key. Just another column that happens to be indexed. (And it doesn't have a problem with duplicate values.)

As a further point of interest, the `date` column is also indexed, but I don't have any problem setting or modifying this value.

Comment: @AdamsTips  sorry, looked again, thought the 'id' (primary key) was the userID.  I have seen a similar problem before.  I'll see if I can remember what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the data is in the correct format?  If I recall correctly Access will look like it worked with a text data type into a numeric field but won't work correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have tried passing the value as a `String`, `Long`, `Double`, etc... There are no errors, and the field value shows the correct value - till I `.Update` and save the changes. Then it reverts to its previous value. If it was a data type issue, I should get an error from ADO, or it would not be able to set the value in the field.

Comment: I don't know then.  I will tell you in my Access experience I switched to running more execute statements (unless I was looping through data) or DAO (not applicable here) because Access is so flaky.  I would try just writing an insert query and executing it via code.